# Convert String to shortdate time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code. What I am trying to do is if it is a null value for the date return NULL or else return the short date. Example: 12/12/15. I am getting an error:

> When converting a string to DateTime parse the string to take the date     before putting each variable into the DateTime Object.

```
public DateTime? StrToDate(string val)
{      
    DateTime? dt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) 
        ? (DateTime?)null 
        : DateTime.ParseExact(val, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);    
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: What string are you passing to the function?

Comment: First of all, where are you getting that error exactly? That's no error I've ever seen. Secondly you are passing in 2 digits for the year but the parse method explicitly looks for 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more promising solution would be to use `TryParseExact()`. Also the case with TryParseExact or ParseExact is that it only accept the provided format of string to parse it to DateTime.

```
    public static DateTime? StrToDate(string val)
    {
        CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        DateTime dateValue;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(val, "MM/dd/yyyy", enUS,
                                   DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out dateValue))
        {
            return (dateValue);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now the test cases would be like:

```
        // Valid date
        var date = StrToDate("05/01/2000");

        // Null
        var nulldateFromEmpty = StrToDate(string.Empty);

        // Null
        var nullDateFromNullString = StrToDate(null);
```

**Update:** The case if you're expecting to return exactly "12/12/15" then DateTime object represents a structs with all date and time fields so even if the value is parsed from ShortDateTime string(12/12/15) still the object will have default values for time i.e. "12:00:00 AM". To convert those values you can again call `var date = StrToDate("05/01/2015").Value.ToString("MM/dd/yy");`

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try :

var datetime = Convert.ToDateTime("November 25, 1992");

return datetime.ToShortDateString();