# Cannot convert date into specific format

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to convert a `Date` into a specific format, I saw a lot of questions here with the same target but all the proposed solutions return a string, I need to return a `DateTime` in my custom format.

This is my code:

```
private DateTime? _matchCalendarDate = DateTime.Now;

public DateTime? MatchCalendarDate
{
   get
   {
      var date = _matchCalendarDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
      var c = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      return c;
   }
   set
   {
      _matchCalendarDate = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

this return: `8/15/2018 12:00:00 AM` but should return `15/08/2018`

Comment: Because your converting your formatted date to a datetime, so it adds the time to it.  Try just converting to Date, otheriwse it will always have time on it (thus the type is datetime.  And a datetime is a specific format by default

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386839/convert-string-to-shortdate-time

Comment: `DateTime` has no format, its a measurement.  You format it when you `ToString()` it for display.  It can be in whatever format you want.

Comment: Show us the UI code where you need the formated MatchCalendarDate value.

Comment: @Brad how is possible convert only a date?

Comment: Your code is doing nothing more than taking a date and returning that very same date.  Dates don't have formats until you display them.  Once you're displaying them, then you use a specific format to determine how you display the date.  The time portion of your date is nothing more than the precision of the date.  Seeing 08/15/2018 12:00:00 AM for 08/15/2018 is the same as seeing 100.00 for 100.  The values are identical , the only difference is how they look.

Comment: @user10230915 you would do what you are doing now, but just not return it as a datetime, just return a string.  Or move the formatting of the date to wherever you are displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say it returns `8/15/2018 12:00:00 AM`, I'm guessing you're simply calling `ToString()` on the property, like so:

```
MatchCalendarDate.ToString();
```

The thing is, a `DateTime` object doesn't have it's own inherent 'format'. It's format is whatever you want it to be.

So when you actually use the property to print the value it returns, you can choose how you want it do be displayed.

Something like;

```
MatchCalendarDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

But then, that essentially renders the conversion in your property redundant. So assuming your intention is to store a `DateTime` object, but retrieve it in the format you like, what you should do is declare a second string property that does the conversion for you.

Answer (score 1):

Return matchCalendarDate.Date; returns the date component, time set to zero

Answer (score 0):

You may have to consider converting to the original format first then to your required format

```
 private  DateTimeDateTime _matchCalendarDate, _matchCalendarD = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime MatchCalendarDate
    {
       get
       {
          var date = _matchCalendarDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

          var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

          var c = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

          return c;
       }
       set
       {
          _matchCalendarDate = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
       }
    }
```

Comment: This would not compile

Comment: The code was autoformated by the app. I Edited the Answer. Please check if it still applies.